# Xcode - Не работает определения место положения

Tags: xcode, swift

Хотел бы узнать по какой причине в эмуляторе не работает данная функция.
Код не прилагаю ибо да же стандартное приложения карты не определяет место положения.

> Notice: Данная функция работает только если использовать эмуляцию

Выводит вот такое сообщение:

```
Текущая геопозиция недоступна
Сейчас определить Вашу геопозицию невозможно
```

Comment: не уверен, что понял вопрос, но все же. Симулятор не может определить ваше положение, потому что в нем нет gps модуля (ну это ж симулятор все таки). Для тестирования вы можете использовать Debug -> Location из меню, и задать нужную вам позицию вручную

Comment: вы правильно поняли но раньше то работало )) разве они убрали эту функцию ?

Comment: Что то мне смутно вспоминается, что когда то вроде по умолчанию было выставлено Купертино. Видимо в какой то версии убрали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, это баг симулятора. Когда делал по примеру работу с картой, при запуске на симуляторе нормально определяло Сан-Франциско. После пары запусков на симуляторе переставало опеределять эту позицию. Когда запускал симулятор, где еще не пробовал эту программу, все работало несколько запусков и снова так же. Т.е запустил на 4s, поработал, перестало - запускаю 5. Потом 5s и т.д.